# Tkinter image disappear

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I would like to open many images in Tkinter using PIL, but when I do, it always gives "Fail to allocate bitmap" error.
I tried creating a Label once, and update the Label, but then the image first opened disapears.

This is how I have tried to update the Label:

```py
from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root= Tk()

root.geometry("800x600")


sprite_img_tmp = Label(root)

sprite_img_tmp.grid(row = 5,column = 0, columnspan=2, sticky = W )


sprite_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\Images\\hero_right.png"))

sprite_img_tmp.config(image = sprite_img)

sprite_img_tmp.image = sprite_img

def callback(e):

    sprite_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("F:\\hero_left.png"))

    sprite_img_tmp.config(image = sprite_img)

    sprite_img_tmp.image = sprite_img

    sprite_img_tmp.place(x=200, y=200)


root.bind("<Return>", callback)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce issue. Note that your code has typo error: `sprinte_img_tmp.grid(...)` should be `sprite_img_tmp.grid(...)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error. If you press ENTER, another image will appear, but the first one will disappear.

Comment: It is expected because you used same label for the two images.

Comment: But if I use another label many times, I get the "Fail to allocate bitmap" error.

Comment: It seems like memory issue which cannot be resolved if too many images are shown together at the same time.